# Use a recursive function to determine if the value passed in is a possible score in the game

Tags: c#, recursion

Important info: Scoring in the game is limited to two plays, with one play being 9 points and the other being 4 points.
Players can score multiple plays in a game 9 (i.e. if 26 was passed in as a value then the method returns true because there is a combination of 9's and 4's that equals 26).
Ex: 9+4+9+4 equals 26, so it is a possible score in the game.
If 19 was passed in, then the method must return false because there is no combination of 9's and 4's that equals 19.
// Edit: Can this function be simplified?
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static bool IsScore(uint aScore) 
{
    if (aScore % 4 == 0 || aScore % 9 == 0 || aScore % 13 == 0)
    { return true; }
    else if (aScore % 9 !< 4 || aScore % 4 !< 9)
    { return false; }
    else
    { return IsScore(aScore - 13); }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I would use `==` rather than all those parentheses and `.Equals` calls, but that's me. Does the function not work?

Comment: First time I've seen `!<`. What does it do?

Comment: Robust code should handle edge cases, e.g. what happens if the score is `-4`, `0`, or `27`?

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi I passed in 27 and it returns true but there is no combination of 9's and 4's that equal 27, so the method should return false. So how can I can adapt my conditions to where it accounts for that?

Comment: @JohnWu passing in 27 returns true and 0 returns true. However, -4 cannot be passed in  as a value because it's not in the range of an unsigned integer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I will change that, as it is not as complicated as using the .Equals call. That was me being extra.

Comment: @GoelzTrol !< checks to see if it is not less than; however, I can represent that in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it recursively without a lot of code and without hardcoding the multipliers:

```
public bool IsMultiple(int input, int[] factors)
{
    if (input < 0) return false;
    if (input == 0) return true;

    foreach (var factor in factors)
    {
        if (input >= factor &&  IsMultiple(input - factor, factors)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call it with

```
var isValidScore = IsMultiple(score, new int[] { 4, 9 } );
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static uint[] numbers = { 4, 9 };
        static uint score = 26;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List<uint> answer = IsScore(null);
           if (answer == null)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("No Answer");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("answer : {0}", string.Join(",", answer));
           }
           Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static List<uint> IsScore(List<uint> answer)
        {
            List<uint> newAnswer = null;
            List<uint> temp = null;
            foreach (uint number in numbers)
            {
                if (answer == null)
                {
                    temp = new List<uint>();
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = new List<uint>(answer);
                }
                temp.Add(number);

                if ((temp.Sum(x => x)) == score)
                {
                    newAnswer = temp;
                    break;
                }
                if (temp.Sum(x => x) < score)
                {
                    newAnswer = IsScore(temp);
                    if (newAnswer != null) break;
                }
            }
            return newAnswer;
        }
    }
}
```